# Having some trouble with Python GUI update

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-idle

```
import sys
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

Gui = Tk()
Gui.title("Exercise Timer")

def jesse(derp):
    x=derp
    test = 0
    while x>=0 and x<=derp:
        if test == 0:
            Gui.after(1000,makeLabel(x))
            x= x-1
            if x==0:
                test = 1
        if test == 1:
            if x == 0:
                Gui.after(1000,makeLabel("brk pls"))
                x=x+1
            else:    
                Gui.after(1000,makeLabel(x))
                x=x+1

def makeLabel(texts):
    Gui.update()
    newlab = Label(text=texts).pack()

def stop():
    Gui.destroy()

mbutton = Button(text="10 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(10)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="20 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(20)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="30 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(30)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="quit",fg="red",command = lambda: stop()).pack()

Gui.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question I have just started getting into Python. Basically my program is to count down from a number, and then count up displaying the next number every 1 second. It all works fine except for when I go to close it. It closes but the function jesse() keeps going and after an error a window pops up with just the next number on it, even though I have clicked the quit button or the windows x button.

Answer (score 0):

"

```
import sys
import time
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

Gui = Tk()
Gui.title("Exercise Timer")

def jesse(derp):
    x=derp
    test = 0
    while x>=0 and x<=derp:
        if test == 0:
            Gui.after(1000,makeLabel(x))
            x= x-1
            if x==0:
                test = 1
        if test == 1:
            if x == 0:
                Gui.after(1000,makeLabel("brk pls"))
                x=x+1
            else:    
                Gui.after(1000,makeLabel(x))
                x=x+1

def makeLabel(texts):
    try:
        Gui.update()
        newlab = Label(text=texts).pack()
    except TclError:
        pass

def stop():
    Gui.destroy()

mbutton = Button(text="10 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(10)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="20 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(20)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="30 seconds",command = lambda: jesse(30)).pack()
mbutton = Button(text="quit",fg="red",command = lambda: stop()).pack()

Gui.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```

"

i added a try and except block so that it stops giving a error, i know its not a very tidy fix but i am unclear on why you code even gives a error.
i hope this helps sorry if it does not